# Is there a record kept of moderator flags raised in chat?

Tags: support, chat, moderation

I'm flagging subtly bitchy comments that are being made about me in SO chat. I'm using the moderator flag rather than the spam inoffensive flag and I'm giving reasons for flagging.

Now, I'm a big boy and can defend myself, but a flame war in chat does nobody any good and just makes the chat room less useful.

But just letting the comments stand is like I'm agreeing with the comments and letting them pass. So after a point I will have to say something. And when the time comes for a mod to approach me I'd like to have a record of trying to get the behaviour to stop.

**Edited to add**

I'm not looking for approval to be offensive. I'll stand by my own actions.

My question is about whether or not a record is kept of the moderator flags that I've raised. All the rest is just background for *why* I am asking.

Comment: From your chat profile: *"... will be mocked"* - isn't that overtly bitchy? Are you expecting people to be flagging your mocking similarly?

Comment: I don't mind being flagged if my behaviour warrants it. And my chat profile is a)honest b)partly tongue in cheek as per the more freewheeling nature of chat c)I tend more to the ignore than the mock d)I'm not just in the chat rooms for the lols - I do answer questions and provide help. Finally - when did this question become about my profile? You're downvoting me because of my profile and not my question?

Comment: I don't agree with the premise of your question - "subtly bitchy" is *way* below the level of what I'd consider to be flag worthy in chat. (There's no examples given though so we're left to infer for ourselves exactly what kind of messages you're referring to of course).

Comment: @Flexo The premise of the question is whether or not records are kept of flags. The rest of it is just background. For the same reason that when I look at SO questions I like to know why someone is asking a particular question in case there is a different solution to the one they are having a problem with. And frankly, this isn't the place to put examples - because, as the answer tells me - they are available to the mods.

Comment: It's chat, really?  There are so many other things to moderate on the sites themselves outside of chat.  Honestly, if people are making comments about you which you don't like, then just ignore them.  You're just perpetrating the annoyance to everyone else.  Note that his statement in chat in no way affects *anything else* on the site, so flagging chat should probably only be done in the most *dire* of circumstances.

Comment: Well _excuse me_ for asking a question about something so trivial. I tell you what - I'll just flag what _I_ consider inappropriate. If you agree with me then you can deal with it - if you don't then feel free to use your moderator powers to smite me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a record of all flags raised *against* a user available for Mods - and I'm pretty sure there's a record of all flags that you've raised as well - just no UI to retrieve that.

Comment: Yep, they're of course kept in the DB, but not exposed anywhere.

Comment: Thanks - that answers my question nicely.

Comment: Are you sure that list contains mod-flags as well? I've only seen spam/offensive flags in there yet

Comment: @MadScientist they do contain mod flagged posts (ex: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Rimmx.png )