# Personal abuse on Stack Overflow Chat

Tags: discussion, chat

Is this type of chat acceptable on Stack Overflow chat?

https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/5035236#5035236
https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/5035253#5035253
https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/5035819#5035819

Comment: I want to add one more link :-http://chat.stackoverflow.com/messages/5018320/history

Comment: @Leena that has been removed :/

Comment: Yes they can.... because they have a lots of Repo. Here all things are judge by user repo. @Leena - me too http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/5035258#5035258

Comment: It all seems rather out of context to me. Difficult to judge if that's really inappropriate. If it's not heavily flagged it does not seem to be too bad.

Comment: @VakulSaini What do you mean? That people with high rep are allowed to say anything they want? If so, that's rather nonsensical.

Comment: Did you try flagging messages? I'm having a hard time understanding what it is about, though there is one message that looks pretty much like a thinly-veiled insult, which would not be acceptable.

Comment: @Bart - Sorry dont take me wrong its not about all.. I'm wonder about it... when he flags me i goes to be blocked... and when i flag him for his abusing comments/chats nothing happen... why it is ???

Comment: @VakulSaini Most likely multiple flags are required to have any effect. You might have been flagged multiple times, while he might have been flagged only once (by you). Not sure though

Comment: Thanks for reporting Jeet :)

Comment: @Bart - I flagged him about 5-6 but nothing happen. :( But if you say so... next time i will be go for more...Thanks :)

Comment: If you will give some time and will look into context, they meant to say one room is full of stupids, and Dogs, what might be more insulting than these.

Comment: @VakulSaini Not more flags by you, more flags by multiple people. But have a look through the questions here on Meta SO to figure out the exact rules on chat flags.

Comment: @jeet Then provide that context. But in any case, you can flag what you find inappropriate and users can be suspended as a result of it. At least for a certain period of time.

Comment: @Bart - Oh okay .... I got it now.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#flagging. `Treat others with the same respect you’d want them to treat you`

Comment: Isn't the general recommendation to just ignore a user who you don't like? And yes - I am the subject of this question.

Comment: No need to mention sir, its pretty clear by seeing the posts that `WHO IS SUBJECT ?`

Comment: surprised why my edit rejected ? @tim

Comment: Would request moderators to check overall history of that room for last 12 hours.

Comment: How this come ? - http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/5036591#5036591

Comment: @programmer_1: @-notifications do not work that way. It was also rejected because it made no sense.

Comment: Going **back** there now and will dig deeper into the transcripts, however there's no sign of profanity that I can see. I don't know if there's anything diamond actionable here, remember that you _can_ ignore people.

Comment: Posted [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115406/insults-and-boorish-behavior-in-chat) a while back. (Potential dupe.)

Comment: We can, I just asked casue its not a social chat room, where peoples abuse each other, in each sentance.

Comment: And at least the person should not repeat the same language, if other persons or groups are not getting this as good, thats only my concern.

Comment: You can do normal chat because we are not machine. But as we are human so we should give respect to each other. Well thats only my opinion.

Comment: `Isn't the general recommendation to just ignore a user who you don't like? And yes - I am the subject of this question` Question is how many times and to what level ???? Every time insult wont work where all are there and all are programmers, no illiterate person who dont have sense to talk

Comment: @DimplePanchal - +1 for to what level.

Comment: I think we'll have this sorted out soon.

Comment: @TimPost - Thank you so much :). One more question ... can we do normal chat ? I think there is a difference b/w simple chat and abusing chat ?

Comment: One Question is in my mind, if I was chating in that room, I was suspended, may be for hindi talks and may be for some meaningless comments that dont address any one, but here why is he not suspended??? Do Reputation matters?? I mean person with more repo can talk what is there in his mind

Comment: @TimPost Long running issue that I tried to raise a while back. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142826/is-there-a-record-kept-of-moderator-flags-raised-in-chat. Although, on reflection, my Parthian shot did cross the line. However - have a seat if you're going to read the transcript - there is more than a couple of day's history to go through.

Comment: @DimplePanchal - I have already mentioned this .... More than 4-5 people need to flag to block any user for 30 minutes.

Comment: @VakulSaini how many of us flagged him and how many times??

Comment: @DimplePanchal - I think how many times doesn't matter... how many people flag ... this matter more. Dont know enough, you can read **Bart** comments.

Comment: Dimple, vakul, let @TimPost try to sort out the matter, the number of flags have brought him here.

Comment: @TimPost Thanks a lot for your time and concerns, sir.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a case of one community splintering off from a larger community with a bit of animosity as the result, which is bound to happen from time to time. What you can walk away with is this:

- If poked, jabbed or just outright insulted, *do not respond*, flag the offending post immediately and use the ignore feature.
- It's generally wise not to go places where you know you won't be well received.
- Moderators are *not* always signed into chat. It may take some time for your flag to be seen and processed. Don't let a bad situation escalate while waiting for us, go find something more constructive to do.
- Remember the part of our venerable FAQ that says *be nice*? That applies everywhere, though the rules in chat *are* a little more relaxed. If we see a pattern of continued disruptions, we will ban people from chat or even shut down an entire room if the problem remains consistent. If you like having nice things, don't abuse them.

With that being said, I am now closing out this *very* localized discussion.

Comment: ..@TimPost- Thanks for giving your time ..."Be Nice" thats what we all want. Thanks Again :)

Answer (score 14):

Not sure if this is acceptable or not, but if *you* think it's not then you can act upon it:

[image]

That's what the flagging system is for, and the moderators can then decide.

Comment: I'm wonder about it... when he flag me i goes to be blocked... and when i flag his abusing comments nothing happen... why it is ???

Comment: @Vakul if you feel something is wrong, contact the team directly and ask.

Comment: Okay i will ... thanks:)

Comment: by how many number of flags a user gets suspended?

Comment: @jeet - More than 5-6 people will have to flag for this. Not bye one.

Comment: ok, got it, thanks :)

Comment: Large tooltip font is large.

Comment: @Bolt - err.. what?

Comment: Your tooltip font is larger than the usual font size.

Comment: @Bolt hmm.. looks like a Chrome mystery.. fine by me though. :)